# Decode binary file in Visual Studio Code programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When trying to open a binary file in Visual Studio Code, the following message will show:

> The file will not be displayed in the editor because it is either binary, very large or uses an unsupported text encoding

This is likely a protection to avoid the editor from freezing.

I would love to decode the file before showing it in the editor and have a function ready to handle that. The problem is, that I never have a chance to run my function since the following code never triggers:

```
vscode.workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument(function (doc) {
    if (doc && doc.fileName.endsWith('.scpt')) {
        console.log("You're trying to open a binary AppleScript file")
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, the API doesn't provide an equivalent event to `onWillSaveTextDocument` for opening files, which would fire before the message above shows. Does anybody know of a different solution?

Comment: Did you ever figure this question out? I have the same requirement as you.

Comment: @loligans I keep checking the changelogs and the [Extension API documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api), but I'm not aware that this is possible by now

Comment: If you haven't already I would recommend upvoting this issue to get this feature implemented into VSCode. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2582

Answer (score 11):

There is an Extension for VSCode called [HexDump](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-hexdump) that you can use to Display a specified file in hexadecimal.

Once installed:

right-click on the file, and select "Show HexDump".

And will display the following:[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in my case I don't even get as far. Code will not open the type of binary file, instead reporting “The file will not be displayed in the editor because it is either binary, very large or uses an unsupported text encoding.”

Comment: There's now an official [Hex Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor) extension